# getJSON not working with WAMP server , Chrome, Firefox

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    
 $.getJSON( "json_data.json", function(data){
  alert("error1");
  $.each(data, function(key, value){
   alert("error");
   $("ul").append( "<li>"+value.name+"</li>");    
  });
    })
 .error(function(data) {
  alert("error2");
  console.log("Error in Json!");
  });  
  });
  
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Fetching data from Mysql database</title>

<head>
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" ></script>
 
</head>

<body>
 <b>Hello </b>
 
 <button>Click me</button>
 
 
</body>

</html>
```

{
        "p1":{
                "name": "person1",
                "age": 25,
                "Company": "ABC",
            },
        "p2";{
                "name": "person2",
                "age": 22,
                "Company": "XYZ",
            },
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `<ul></ul>` tag to html

And correct json format

```
{ "p1":{ 
        "name": "person1", 
        "age": 25,
        "Company": "ABC"
       },
  "p2":{ 
        "name": "person2", 
        "age": 22, 
        "Company": "XYZ" 
       }
}
```